# How to create MULTIPLE LIKE query for the same column in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Let's say I want to get all rows in a text column that contain both of three words (word1, word2, word3)

so my sql would be

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    mytable
WHERE
    col_text LIKE '%word1%'
        AND col_text LIKE '%word2%'
        AND col_text LIKE '%word3%'
```

is there any and_like in codeigniter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supplying three `like()` to the query builder will assume, by default `AND` for each:

```php
$this->db
     ->from( "mytable" )
     ->like( "col_text", 'word1', 'both' )
     ->like( "col_text", 'word2', 'both' )
     ->like( "col_text", 'word3', 'both' );
```